# Why query->next() from QSqlQuery don't work as expected?

Tags: sql, qt

I work on a Qt application linked with a SQLite database. All work fine everywhere in my code except in one place where the command query->next() don't work.

SQL request

```sql
SELECT category.idCategory, category.text FROM Category, Category_User, User WHERE Category_User.category = category.idCategory AND Category_User.user = User.idUser AND User.idUser = 1;
```

The result of the request

```
idCategory | text  |
-----------|-------|
         1 |first  |
         2 |second |
         3 |third  |
         4 |fourth |
```

My code

```cpp
query->exec(<<request above>>)
int value = 0;
while (query->next()) {
    this->category[value] = new Category(query->value("idCategory").toInt(), query->value("text").toString());
    value++;
    }
```

The point is, it enters one only time in the while loop instead of four as expected. Only this->category[0] is filled.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: What does `query->size()` return after `exec()` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. First, i'll try later with JOIN, I heard of it and I know it's better than my method. Second, query->size() returns -1, but I still get the first row of the result of my request.